# Elmah in MVC3 not working, 404 The resource you are looking for has been removed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've set up elmah as described here: 
http://joel.net/wordpress/index.php/2011/02/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp-net-mvc3-part1/
but i keep getting:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The
>   resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Detailed
>   Error Information Module  IIS Web Core
>   Notification  MapRequestHandler
>   Handler   StaticFile Error
>   Code  0x80070002 Requested
>   URL   http://localhost:80/elmah.axd
>   Physical
>   Path  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Rjs\Web\elmah.axd
>   Logon Method  Forms Logon User    shane

I can't figure out what's going on. Please help. this used to work with MVC2.
thanks

Comment: Does the rest of your site work and is it just the `elmah.axd` that is throwing 404s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. i had to map it in IIS. (not sure why)??? but it works:

[image]